# Determine $p$, justifying every step and find all its roots.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $p ∈\Bbb R[x]$ such that $p$ is monic and $\deg(p) = 3$. If we know that $(x − 1)$ divides $p$ and the remainders of $p$ divided by $(x − 2), (x − 3)$ and $(x − 4)$ are all equal, determine $p$, justifying every step and find all its roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$x-1| \ p(x) \Rightarrow p(1)=0$

the equality of remainders implies that $p(2)=p(3)=p(4)$